# Sorting a list using a "a -> a -> Maybe Ordering" function

Tags: sorting, haskell

Is there a variant of

```
sortBy :: (a -> a -> Ordering) -> [a] -> [a]
```

(in Data.List) that allows me to use a `a -> a -> Maybe Ordering` sorting function instead of `a -> a -> Ordering`?

What this variant would do is this:

```
sortBy' :: (a -> a -> Maybe Ordering) -> [a] -> Maybe [a]
```

If `a -> a -> Maybe Ordering` ever returns `Nothing` when it's called during the sort, `sortBy'` would return `Nothing`. Otherwise it would return the sorted list wrapped in `Just`.

If such a variant is not already available, can you please help me construct one? (Preferably one that is at least as efficient as `sortBy`.)

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea. Whether or not the result is `Nothing` will depend on which comparisons are made, and which comparisons are made will depend on which sorting algorithm is used. To check that all possible comparisons are `Just` would take O(n^2) time.

Comment: I think it would be beneficial if you described to us what you are trying to achieve with this. Why not just ensure that you are passing valid data to `sortBy` beforehand? Is there a use case in mind? If you do this, we may be able to help better.

Comment: I could imagine using such a function for a *topological* sort, where if the return value was `Nothing` then you could arbitrarily pick one or the other to come first. But in that case, you could just as well have the function return `LT` instead of `Nothing`, and still use `sortBy`.

Comment: @chepner, can't you mess things up trying to do a topological sort like that? You could conclude `x<y` and later `y<x`.

Comment: @Cirdec this _could_ be well-defined and algorithm-agnostic if the comparison function has some extra properties, for instance if the comparison only fails when the elements are sufficiently close, but then fails consistently. In this case, aborting during the sorting process is the most efficient thing to do: the sorting brings neighbouring elements ever closer together, but avoids unnecessary work if you already get a failure at some point before the list is completely sorted (where you would ultimately get a failure anyway).

Comment: @leftaroundabout @Cirdec I think it's enough to have transitivity: i.e. whenever two comparisons `x<y,y<z` both succeed (`isJust`) with `LT`, then the comparison `x<z` must succeed with `LT` (ditto for `GT,EQ`, including mixed cases). When that happens and the sort returns `Just`, the comparisons performed by `sort` should be enough to guarantee that the comparison always succeeds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can adapt quickSort :

```
quickSortBy :: (a -> a -> Maybe Ordering) -> [a] -> Maybe [a]
quickSortBy f [] = Just []
quickSortBy f (x:xs) = do
  comparisons <- fmap (zip xs) $ mapM (f x) xs
  sortLesser <- quickSortBy f . map fst $ filter ((`elem` [GT, EQ]) . snd) comparisons
  sortUpper <- quickSortBy f . map fst $ filter ((== LT) . snd) comparisons
  return $ sortLesser ++ [x] ++ sortUpper
```

At least assume that your sorting predicate `f :: a -> a -> Maybe Ordering` is anti-symmetric : `f x y == Just LT` if and only if `f y x == Just GT`. Then when `quickSortBy f` returns `Just [x1,...,xn]`, I think you have this guarantee : for all i in [1..n-1], `f xi x(i+1)` is `Just LT` or `Just EQ`.

When in particular f is a partial order (transitive), then [x1,...,xn] is totally ordered.